# Angular material: Programmatic "next" for linear stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-stepper

I want to use the [angular material stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) but I need to do some asynchronous service call before proceeding to a second step. How can I achieve this? I could add a click handler to the next button but that will not wait for the async call to come back and proceed anyway. [Here is a plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uCvGWMHUt3hu95I7GIPG?p=preview).

In the html template I would have the button:

```
  <button mat-button matStepperNext (click)="onNext()">Next</button>
```

In the component:

```
  onNext() {
     let promise = service.validateData()
  }
```

Is there a way using the [completed](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#completed-step) step attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you can include a indentifier to your stepper,

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper linear>
```

next you can change the step button to a normal one:

```
<button mat-button (click)="onNext(stepper)">Next</button>
```

On your component you can call your service and call the step advance (note that you need to include the MatStepper from '@angular/material')

```
onNext(stepper: MatStepper) {
     let promise = service.validateData();
     stepper.next();
  }
```

Comment: Only thing I had to add the stepper parameter into the onNext() call, i.e. `<button mat-button (click)="onNext(stepper)">Next</button>`

Comment: exactly, sorry to miss that one.

Comment: This presents a problem for testing; you need to be able to get the stepper reference in order to pass it into that function.